# Modify htaccess to work in subfolders

Tags: multi-site-manager, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup a multilanguage site using this solution http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine

I have to modify the .htaccess to remove index.php from URL event in the subfolder but I don't know how. The current .htaccess is this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This file is located in /en/ folder and should point to right index.php in the same folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a `/en/` before `/index.php?/$1 [L]`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```